# Is this tutorial wrong?

Tags: python, sql, flask

While looking over a tutorial on the Flask module I came across something that i need to confirm is incorrect which is this

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_sqlite.htm

```
 finally:
    return render_template("result.html",msg = msg)
    con.close()
```

After a return it tried to call code which from my knowledge is impossible? I assume they want to put the con.close() above the return.

Comment: Correct, the code after the return won't be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

As someone who has written courses and delivered them I will say that creating tutorial code is hard because on one hand you want to avoid stupid mistakes like this but on the other hand you are writing for the student as an audience rather than the computer, so making sure that the code is tested is a bit of a problem.

So this is a general systemic problem with tutorials generally.